# Moodle Video file with scrollbars

Tags: video, scrollbar, moodle

I see the following error in firebug. The object height and width is overwritten at runtime. Also the video is seen with horizontal and vertical scrollbars.

Click [Introduction.html](http://moodle-vpc-backend.iss-resources.com/sep/pluginfile.php/4/mod_resource/content/0/Test/test.html) link to view the file.

Please let me know how i can get rid of the scrollbars

Answer (score 0):

Try setting width and height properties that fit correctly your video resolution.
Can you give more details about your video integration in Moodle ?